# sql not importing excel sheet correctly - leaving off columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, import-from-excel, sql-import-wizard

I am trying to import a 386 x 386 matrix from excel to SQL Server.
When I use the Import and Export Wizard everything seems to work correctly but when I check the created table it cuts off from column 255 onwards, i.e. I am left with 386 rows and 255 columns.
Does SQL have a limit as to the number of columns imported/displayed?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you check if you have a blank column after 255th column in your excel?

Comment: I do not have a blank column after the 255th column in the excel file. I am using the 2016 64-bit version of Excel, 64-bit version of SQL, the 64-bit Import Wizard and it still would not work properly. The only way I can get it to import correctly is first converting the excel file to a text file and then bringing it into SQL.